# ¿Cómo cambiar el scroll infinito de este script por uno finito?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código que me va cargando las imágenes cuando bajo el scroll, pero las mismas imágenes siguen apareciendo a medida que sigo bajando el scroll, lo hace indefinidamente, quiero que al encontrar la última imágen finalice.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
waterFall();
var dataInt={"data":[{"src":"0.jpg"},{"src":"1.jpg"},{"src":"2.jpg"},{"src":"3.jpg"}]};
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
if(checkScrollSlide()){
    $.each(dataInt.data,function(key,value){
        var oBox=$('<div>').addClass('box').appendTo($('#main'));
        var oPic=$('<div>').addClass('pic').appendTo(oBox);
        $('<img>').attr('src','images/'+$(value).attr('src')).appendTo(oPic);
    });
    waterFall();
}
});
});

function waterFall() {
  var $boxs=$('#main>div');
  var w=$boxs.eq(0).outerWidth();
  var cols=Math.floor($(window).width()/w);
  $("#main").width(w*cols).css('margin','0 auto');
  var hArr=[];
  $boxs.each(function(index,value){
  var h=$boxs.eq(index).outerHeight();
  if(index<cols){
    hArr.push(h);
  }else {
    minH=Math.min.apply(null,hArr);
    var minHeightIndex=$.inArray(minH,hArr);
    $(value).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':minH+'px',
        'left':minHeightIndex*w+'px'
    });
    hArr[minHeightIndex]+=$boxs.eq(index).outerHeight();
}
});
}

// scroll infinito

function checkScrollSlide() {
  var $lastBox=$('#main>div').last();
  var lastBoxDis=$lastBox.offset().top+Math.floor($lastBox.outerHeight()/2);
  var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
  var documentH=$(window).height();
  return (lastBoxDis<scrollTop+documentH)?true:false;

}
```

Cada vez que hago scroll se genera un array con las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El html:

```
 <body>
 <div id="main">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/01.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/03.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/05.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/06.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/07.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/08.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/09.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/10.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/11.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/12.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/10.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/11.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/12.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/13.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/14.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/15.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/16.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/17.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/18.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="pic"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/19.jpg"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías contar la cantidad de `main>div` que han ido cargandose, y compararlo con el tamaño del array.
Para aprovechar la función `checkScrollSlide()`, trata de hacer algo como ésto:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
var dataInt={"data":[{"src":"0.jpg"},{"src":"1.jpg"},{"src":"2.jpg"},{"src":"3.jpg"}]};
var NumberOfItems = dataInt.data.length;
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
if(checkScrollSlide(NumberOfItems)){
    $.each(dataInt.data,function(key,value){
        var oBox=$('<div>').addClass('box').appendTo($('#main'));
        var oPic=$('<div>').addClass('pic').appendTo(oBox);
        $('<img>').attr('src','images/'+$(value).attr('src')).appendTo(oPic);
    });
}
});
});

// scroll infinito

function checkScrollSlide(NumberOfItems) {
    if($('#main>div').length >= NumberOfItems)
      return false;
    var $lastBox=$('#main>div').last();
    var lastBoxDis=$lastBox.offset().top+Math.floor($lastBox.outerHeight()/2);
    var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
    var documentH=$(window).height();
    return (lastBoxDis<scrollTop+documentH)?true:false;
}
```

Los cambios han sido:
`var NumberOfItems = dataInt["data"].length;` para contar la cantidad de imágenes en el array, y así pasarlo como argumento a la función `checkScrollSlide(NumberOfItems)`
En dicha función, se obtienen la cantidad de `main>div` y se compara su tamaño con el agumento `NumberOfItems` y devolver `false` para que deje de cargar items indefinidamente.

EDIT: He eliminado por completo el metodo `waterfall`, ya que el css del OP se encarga de colocar los elementos en cuadrícula, ajustandose automáticamente sin necesidad de utilizar javascript.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... Lo hice pero igualmente está el scroll infinito... Obtuve el valor de la variable NumberOfItems y corresponde al número de fotos, pero igualmente el scroll es infinito.

Comment: agregaste el if dentro de la funcion checkScrollSlide ? me refiero a: if($('#main>div').length >= NumberOfItems)
      return false;
Comprobe el código como medianamente pude ya que no conozco el html y me funcionó
Edito: mirando otra pregunta que tienes, muestras el html de la galería. Alli los div están dentro del div id "gallery" y no de "main". Revisa por si has cambiado el nombre no sea problema de que el if deba llevar gallery>div

Comment: Si coloqué el if, si tengo varias pruebas y en una tengo gallery en vez de main pero en este caso uso main

Comment: imprimo con console.log(dataInt.data); y me trae el array con las fotos indefinidamente, voy a subir el capture a la pregunta

Comment: Ya subí la imagen

Comment: Comprueba el valor de $('#main>div').length dentro de la funcion checkScrollSlide para verificar que la cantidad sea igual o menor a la cantidad de elementos del array

Comment: No me devuelve ningún valor

Comment: Voy a agregar el Html, en el se cargan las primera 20 fotos con html y el resto se cargan enel scroll leidas por el array var dataInt

Comment: Te dejo un enlace de muestra, http://jsfiddle.net/9r72t8ug/ comprueba el funcionamiento ya que a mi me da el resultado que esperas, unicamente carga las imagenes del array y una vez alcanza esas ya no sigue haciendo scroll

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí funcionó... Debo revisar porqué antes no lo hizo. Pero al cargarlas por primeravez, las fotos que se cargan después del scroll se montan una sobre otras y cuando refresco la página se muestran bien, sabrás por qué?

Comment: invoca al metodo waterFall(); despues de la comprobacion para que setee los valores en la posicion posicion de los ultimos elementos agregados. Únicamente ten en cuenta que si lo pones directamente el metodo va a ser llamado constantemente a pesar de no cargar mas imagenes. Siento no darte el codigo de ejemplo ahora, ando con el tiempo justo, pero tampoco queria dejarte sin respuesta. Nada mas que pueda agrego el codigo

Comment: Hola, después de cual comprobación? porque lo puse envarios puntos y no lo logré. Disculpa

Comment: Disculpa la demora, fue error mio al decirte eso, con las prisas no me fije bien. Por favor comprueba este ejemplo, http://jsfiddle.net/9p6m7nru/ 
Las imagenes que carga lo hace correctamente una encima de otra sin solaparlas

Comment: Bueno lo probé e inicialmente me parece que había funcionado, pero si funciona mejor, solo que un par de fotos se solapan. Yo he realizado cambios al código y quizás por eso me han dejado de funcionar cosas, también la galería se solapa con los demás Div´s (Los de abajos en este caso).

Comment: El código funciona de la siguiente manera actualmente, tengo un index donde por defecto se cargan las fotos de 2020, desde el controlador hago la lectura de las fotos en la BD y la consulta me devuelve los primero 20 registros para mostrarlos en el html, luego el resto con la consulta genero un archivo .json donde se guarda la información para la lectura desde el script con el que me estás ayudando, y al hacer scroll se cargan las imágenes faltantes, pero agregué a las fotos dos botones de ver(para ampliar) y descargar... También se los agregué al script para que se muestren con los del json

Comment: Pero desde un pill nav de boostrap tengo unos enlaces para cambiar de año y por ende de galería, en eso esto trabajando actualmente y es la pregunta que viste que tengo similar, de momento lo que hago es pasarle el valor del año por la url y me cargan las fotos correspondientes y me genera el .json del año actual y en el navegador por medio de la consola web veo que me genera el array pero no me despliega las fotos al hacer scroll solo con el 2020

Comment: No hay manera por este medio de contactarte para enviarte el proyecto y que me ayudes remuneradamente?

Comment: Agregame a discord kingcreek#2475 una vez resuelto el problema lo agrego a la respuesta para ayudar a quien pueda llegar a tener un problema similar

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, ya resolví todo.